# Перевод из std::wstring в число

Tags: c++

Если у меня есть указатель на строку в середине которой содержится число. Я могу перевести в число примерно так:

```
wchar_t* begin = L"A12A";
begin++;
wchar_t* end;
unsigned long n = ::wcstoul(begin, &end, 10);
```

А как мне сделать подобное если число содержится в `std::wstring` и есть итератор на начало числа:

```
std::wstring wstr(L"A12B")
std::wstring::iterator it = wstr.begin();
it++;
//Получаем число
```

И на выходе итератор должен указывать на B;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у тебя есть только итератор под рукой и нет родительского (к итератору) объекта (строка), тогда можно вот так сделать

```
wchar_t* itAddress = &(*it);
unsigned long n = ::wcstoul(itAddress, L'\0', 10);
```

Т.е. через итератор получаем указатель на данные, которые хранятся в строке (итератор для строки по себе сам указатель по сути, его просто надо правильно преобразовать)

Если у тебя есть родительская строка, то можно сделать так:

```
unsigned long n = ::wcstoul(wstr.c_str() + 1, L'\0', 10);
```

Т.е. сразу легально (средствами строки) получаем указатель на данные, которые хранятся в строке

**P.S.**

Чуть скорректировал код чтобы определять где функция wcstoul закончила работу

```
wchar_t* itAddress = &(*it);
wchar_t* itAddressEnd = 0;

unsigned long n = ::wcstoul(itAddress + 1, &itAddressEnd, 10);

std::wstring::iterator itNew = it + ((long long)itAddressEnd - (long long)itAddress - 2);
```

`-2` потому что 1) начали с символа it+1 - это дало `-1`, 2) закончили на предыдущем символе - это дало еще `-1`

Comment: Да, как через итератор получить указатель это понятно, но мне бы хотелось сделать так что бы итератор указывал  на место где закончился разбор строки как это делает `wcstoul`, потому что дальше должен пойти парсинг оставшихся символов.

Comment: Anton, мой косяк, я со вторым параметром ступил, в P.S. выше добавил как надо делать, чтобы получить итератор на следующую часть текста

Answer (score 1):

В голову приходит только решение вроде такого

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  wstring wstr(L"A1298BAAC");
  wstring::iterator it = wstr.begin();
  it++;
  wchar_t* result_it;
  auto x = wcstoul(&*it, &result_it, 10);

  wstring::iterator it2 =  wstr.begin();
  while(it2 != wstr.end() && &*it2++ != result_it){
  }

  int pos = std::distance(wstr.begin(), it2) - 1;

  std::wcout << x << endl << result_it << endl << pos << endl <<  wstr.substr(pos);
}
```

И вывод

```
1298
BAAC
5
BAAC
```